# Find group of strings starting and ending by a character using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have a string, and I want to extract, using regular expressions, groups of characters that are between the character `:` and the other character `/`.
typically, here is a string example I'm getting:

```
'abcd:45.72643,4.91203/Rou:hereanotherdata/defgh'
```

and so, I want to retrieved, `45.72643,4.91203` and also `hereanotherdata`
As they are both between characters `:` and  `/`.

I tried with this syntax in a easier string where there is only 1 time the pattern,

```
[tt]=regexp(str,':(\w.*)/','match')

tt =    ':45.72643,4.91203/'
```

but it works only if the pattern happens once. If I use it in string containing multiples times the pattern, I get all the string between the first `:` and the last `/`.

How can I mention that the pattern will occur multiple time, and how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
regexp(str, '(?<=:).+?(?=/)', 'match')
```

Example (Matlab R2016b):

```
>> str = 'abcd:45.72643,4.91203/Rou:hereanotherdata/defgh';
>> result = regexp(str, '(?<=:).+?(?=/)', 'match')
result =
  1×2 cell array
    '45.72643,4.91203'    'hereanotherdata'
```

Comment: thanks! it seems working well. it took me some time to decode the syntax but i think i got it. :)

Comment: That happens with regular expressions :-D

Answer (score 1):

In most languages this is hard to do with a single regexp. Ultimately you'll only ever get back the one string, and you want to get back multiple strings.

I've never used Matlab, so it may be possible in that language, but based on other languages, this is how I'd approach it...

I can't give you the exact code, but a search indicates that in Matlab there is a function called strsplit, example...

```
C = strsplit(data,':')
```

That should will break your original string up into an array of strings, using the ":" as the break point. You can then ignore the first array index (as it contains text before a ":"), loop the rest of the array and regexp to extract everything that comes before a "/".

So for instance...

```
'abcd:45.72643,4.91203/Rou:hereanotherdata/defgh'
```

Breaks down into an array with parts...

```
1 - 'abcd'
2 - '45.72643,4.91203/Rou'
3 - 'hereanotherdata/defgh'
```

Then Ignore 1, and extract everything before the "/" in 2 and 3.

Comment: You can indeed do a double `strsplit` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

As John Mawer and Adriaan mentioned, `strsplit` is a good place to start with. You can use it for both ':' and '/', but then you will not be able to determine where each of them started. If you do it with `strsplit` twice, you can know where the ':' starts :

```
A='abcd:45.72643,4.91203/Rou:hereanotherdata/defgh';
B=cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,'/'),strsplit(A,':'),'uniformoutput',0);
```

Now B has cells that start with ':', and has two cells in each cell that contain '/' also. You can extract it with checking where B has more than one cell, and take the first of each of them:

```
C=cellfun(@(x) x{1},B(cellfun('length',B)>1),'uniformoutput',0)

C =

1×2 cell array

    '45.72643,4.91203'    'hereanotherdata'
```

Comment: yes, the strsplit was what i was using until now. but i was thinking that regular expression could do it more easily maybe. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 16b you can use extractBetween:

```
 >> str = 'abcd:45.72643,4.91203/Rou:hereanotherdata/defgh';
 >> result = extractBetween(str,':','/')

 result =

   2×1 cell array

     {'45.72643,4.91203'}
     {'hereanotherdata' }
```

If all your text elements have the same number of delimiters this can be vectorized too.

Comment: wow i didn't know this function! it is a new one. that's nice, i work in 2016b. i will check this function in detail. thanks!